# How to parse out nested repeater in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a store in Angular and I have multiple categories with products in each category. I would like to break out each category into a separate div and then list out each product in a separate div.

Here is what I want the output to look like:

```html
<div>
  <h2>category1</h2>
  <div>Product 1</div>
  <div>Product 2</div>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>category2</h2>
  <div>Product 3</div>
  <div>Product 4</div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);

  app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.items = products;
  });
 
  var products = [{
    category1: [{
      name: "Product 1",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
    }, {
      name: "Product 2",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
    }],
    category2: [{
      name: "Product 3",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
    }, {
      name: "Product 4",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
    }]
  }];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">

    <div ng-repeat="category in store.items">
      <h2>{{category}}</h2> <!-- Category title here -->
      <div ng-repeat="item in category">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Here's a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pgJuR8qWBGuWJ1aJ6IAE)

Comment: your plunker not work!

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: See [this edited plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iS0BGXbhFDH7B6PR0XOm?p=preview). I think you'll have to rewrite your json/object to let it make more sense. You start with an array which only has one item, which in turn is an object and not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` should look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in store.items[0]">
    <h2>category{{$index+1}}</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="item in category">
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's working example:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('store', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.items = [{
    something: [{
      name: "Product 1",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
    }, {
      name: "Product 2",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
    }],
    category2: [{
      name: "Product 3",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
    }, {
      name: "Product 4",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
    }]
  }];;
  });

 
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">

  <div ng-repeat="(key, category) in store.items[0]">
    <h2>{{key}}</h2>
    <!-- Category title here -->
    <div ng-repeat="item in category">
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For the `h2` is there any way to grab the actual name of the category rather than hardcoding the word "category" and then tagging on a number?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend structuring your data in a slightly different way so it's easier to parse.

javascript:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);

    app.controller('StoreController', function() {
        this.categories = categories;
    });

    var categories= [
      {
         name: "Category 1",
         products:  [{
            name: "Product 1",
            description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
         },{ 
            name: "Product 2",
            description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
         }],
     },{
         name: "Category 2",
         products:  [{
            name: "Product 3",
            description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
       },{ 
          name: "Product 4",
          description: "Lorem ipsum dalor sit amet"
       }],
     }];
})();
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">

    <div ng-repeat="category in store.categories">
      <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
      <div ng-repeat="product in category"><h4>product.name</h4></div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Wr83nz47aUJpSQgSaHL3?p=preview